# How to find the array name where a property does not exist?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I define the session name based on the array of objects in the data, and then it renders whether it is a session or an item. When rendering a session, if the session has the property 'nome,' it will display 'section.nome,' but not all sessions have the 'nome' property. I would like it so that if the 'nome' property does not exist in the session array, the name of that array is rendered instead. For instance, the section 'horarioIntervalo' does not have the property 'nome', so I would like it to render 'horarioIntervalo'. Is it possible?

```
const data = [
  {
    _id: "64e502ec6b4bfaafb4e1466c",
    nome: "ESF Centro - Médico",
    endereco: {
      rua: "Angelo Perucchi, 30 - Centro",
    },
    fone: "48 3444 6065",
    especialidades: [
      {
        _id: "64e500d16b4bfaafb4e14667",
        nome: "Clínico Geral - Consulta",
        profissionais: [
          {
            _id: "6405d8f341fb166e83f43f5d",
            nome: "Braulio Portela",
            label: "Braulio Portela",
            value: "6405d8f341fb166e83f43f5d",
            horarioIntervalo: [
              {
                dias: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                intervalo: {
                  inicio: "12:00",
                  fim: "13:00",
                },
              },
              {
                dias: [5],
                intervalo: {
                  inicio: "13:00",
                  fim: "17:00",
                },
              },
              {
                dias: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                intervalo: {
                  inicio: "10:00",
                  fim: "11:40",
                },
              },
              {
                dias: [1, 2, 3, 4],
                intervalo: {
                  inicio: "15:00",
                  fim: "16:40",
                },
              },
              {
                dias: [5],
                intervalo: {
                  inicio: "13:00",
                  fim: "15:00",
                },
              },
            ],
            espacoAgendamento: "00:30",
            periodoAtendimento: {
              inicio: "2023-08-22",
              fim: "2023-12-31",
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

```
  function renderSection(section, sectionIndex, parentIndex) {
    const combinedIndex = `${parentIndex}-${sectionIndex}`;
    return (
      <div key={combinedIndex}>
        <div
          onClick={() => toggleSection(combinedIndex)}
          style={{
            cursor: "pointer",
            padding: "10px",
            border: "1px solid #ccc",
            background: selectedSections[combinedIndex] ? (parentIndex === sectionIndex ? "yellow" : "green") : parentIndex === sectionIndex ? "red" : "blue",
          }}>
          {section.nome}
        </div>
        {selectedSections[combinedIndex] && renderItems(section, combinedIndex)}
      </div>
    );
  }

  return <div>{data.map((section, index) => renderSection(section, index, index))}</div>;
```

I tried using Object method like:

```
   const sectionArray = Object.keys(section).filter((key) => Array.isArray(section[key]));
   console.log("sectionArray", sectionArray);

{section.nome ? section.nome : sectionArray}
```

But it is returning:

```
sectionArray ['especialidades']
sectionArray ['especialidades']
sectionArray ['profissionais']
sectionArray ['horarioIntervalo']
sectionArray ['dias']
sectionArray ['dias']
sectionArray ['dias']
sectionArray ['dias']
sectionArray ['dias']
sectionArray ['horarioIntervalo']
sectionArray ['profissionais']
sectionArray ['especialidades']
sectionArray ['especialidades']
```

And for some reason the name replaced is dias, not horarioIntervalo

Comment: have you tried setting a check in the  `renderSection()`  function to see if the 'nome' property exists in the section object and to either render the 'nome' property or the array name ?

Comment: I tried something like:
```const sectionName = section.nome || `Session ${sectionIndex + 1}`; ```
But what you are saying is exactly what I want, but I could not figure it out how to do that.  Tried to use the Object Methods, but no success.

Answer (score 0):

You could try Modifying the `renderSection()` to check whether the 'nome' property exists in the section object and render either the 'nome' property or the array name accordingly.

> **TRY**
>
> ```
> const combinedIndex = `${parentIndex}-${sectionIndex}`;   
> const sectionName = section.nome || `Array ${parentIndex}`;
>      return (
>     <div key={combinedIndex}>
>       <div
>         onClick={() => toggleSection(combinedIndex)}
>         style={{
>           cursor: "pointer",
>           padding: "10px",
>           border: "1px solid #ccc",
>           background: selectedSections[combinedIndex] ? (parentIndex === sectionIndex ? "yellow" : "green") : parentIndex === sectionIndex ? "red" : "blue",
>         }}>
>         {sectionName}
>       </div>
>       {selectedSections[combinedIndex] && renderItems(section, combinedIndex)}
>     </div>   ); }
>
> return <div>{data.map((section, index) => renderSection(section,
> index, index))}</div>;
> ```

Hope it Solves the problem ;)

Comment: It doesn't. It returns the parentIndex, which is: ```1-1-0-0```.